# Socket Policy File Server & AIR3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, sockets, air

Edit: So i'm trying to connect to a IRC server using AIR3.0. No matter what, i always get

```
:server_ip NOTICE AUTH :*** Looking up your hostname...
:server_ip NOTICE AUTH :*** Found your hostname (cached)
 ERROR :Closing Link: [server_ip] (Ping timeout)
```

Here is just a bunch of code :

```
    private function handleSocketData(__e:ProgressEvent):void { 
        receiveData();
    }


    private function receiveData():void{
        var str:String =_socket.readUTFBytes(_socket.bytesAvailable);           
        txt.text += str;                
    }

    private function sendData(__str:String):void{
        _socket.writeUTFBytes(__str);
        _socket.flush();            
    }
```

I just do a classic _socket.connect(server_ip, server_port); and i have a bunch of listeners for the socket like ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA, Event.CLOSE, Event.CONNECT ...
Nothing fancy.
But no matter what, i can connect to the irc server, but it always stops at Found your hostname then nothing happens (no more data is sent my way) and i get a disconnection a few seconds after...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AIR doesn't require a socket policy, only Flash does, so that's not your issue here. Unfortunately I can't tell you what the real problem is based on the information you've posted. Please provide more details and maybe someone can tell you what the real problem is.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i wasn't sure about that. I'll post some code.

Comment: Sounds like its the IRC client that is hanging up on you, so not a code issue. Perhaps its expecting you to send something up that you aren't?